# How to allow to copy only given file via ssh?

Tags: security, ssh, sshd

I configured my `authorized_keys` as:

```
from="192.168.1.*",restrict ssh-rsa AAAA***
```

`tty` is restricted, but remote user still can run commands on my side:
(Notice lines marked as `<<<<<<`. These are the commands I have typed)

```
$ ssh kes
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
No mail.
asdf                    <<<<<<
-bash: line 1: asdf: command not found
ls                      <<<<<<
bin
work
x
: > test                <<<<<<
echo "sdf" > test2      <<<<<<
cat test2               <<<<<<
sdf
```

Why connection still interactive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic is: `command="cat ~/t/db/tucha.sql.gz"`. In combination with `restrict` it will allow user only this one thing.

I add it to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file:

```
from="192.168.1.*",restrict,command="cat ~/t/db/tucha.sql.gz" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EXXXXXXXXX name
```

When user connect to my host he will get dump of `tucha.sql.gz` file.

He must connect using command: `ssh myhost > local.name.sql.gz`

Thus output from from host will be saved into `local.name.sql.gz` file